# To check the convergence of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I tried to find out if this integral is convergent or divergent,

$$\int _0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(\frac{\ln\left(\sin x\right)}{\sqrt{x}\:}\right)\:dx$$

I know that the problematic point is near $x=0$, and

$$\ln \left(\sin\left(x\right)\right)=\ln\left(x\right)+\ln\left(\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}\right)$$

so near $x=0$,

$$\ln\left(\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{x}\right)\rightarrow 0$$

But from here is don't know how to bound the function with another convergent one.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, since $x^{-1/2}$ is integrable over $[0,1]$, it accounts to deciding whether $$\exists \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \int_\delta^1x^{-1/2}\ln x\,dx\in \mathbb R$$

Let's deal with the more general $$\lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \int_\delta^1 x^\alpha\ln x\,dx$$

Let's make the substitution $y:=\ln x\implies dy={dx\over x}=e^{-y}dx$.

It becomes

$$\lim_{M\to\, -\infty} \int_M^0 y\,e^{(\alpha+1) y}\,dy=-\lim_{T\to\,+\infty}\int_0^Ty\,e^{-(\alpha+1) y}\,dy$$

The last one is notoriously convergent if and only if $\alpha>-1$

So, indeed, your case $\alpha=-{1\over 2}$ is of convergence.

Comment: As you said, @Matan, you can split the integrand into $$x^{-1/2}\ln(x)+x^{-1/2}\ln\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)$$ Since $\ln\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)\to 0$, the second half is dominated by (say) $1000\cdot x^{-1/2}$, which can be integrated in $[0,1]$ ($x^{-1/2}$ has $2\sqrt{x}$ as a primitive). So you only need to check the limit of the first part.

Comment: Thank you. now it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

The integrand behaves as $\log(x)/\sqrt{x}$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ which is an integrable singularity..